# Custom Details Description

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I can not find a single example/tutorial on how to create a custom details description presenter. For example, I would like to do something similar to the Google Play Movies, where they put more information between the title and the description, like release year, rotten tomatoes, rating, etc.

Is there any good place I could find an example?

Thank you
T

Comment: http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-5-138.html

Comment: Incase you still want to work with old details page design. instead of using the layout built inside the framework get the layout into your project and customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a similar custom class starting from [AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c7a9fedaf3b8303f2d17b01a20ebea1efcec103d/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter.java) and use a different layout than the used on:

```
@Override
public final ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.lb_details_description, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```